# How to copy excel table with formatting into word - Manual Operation

Tags: excel, ms-word

As shown in the figure, I have the table below in Excel with conditional formatting (arrow symbols in each cell)

[Image 1: In Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA5LV.png)

I want to copy the same table from Excel to Word with conditional formatting. While copying and pasting to Word, the arrow in each cell is missing. The same is shown in the image below. Please tell me how to copy and paste the same as the excel table shown in image 1.

[Image 2: After copying and pasting from Excel to Word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoPQk.png)

Comment: This is not a programming question. As such, it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word should be asked on an appropriate end-use forum (e.g., MS Answers).

Comment: Hi @bem, did the answer below solve your question?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use Paste Special:

[image]

and then use the Microsoft Excel Worksheet Object option? That let me copy the icons from Excel into Word.

[image]

For example:

Excel screenshot:

[image]

Word screenshot, after pasting as per the instructions above:

[image]

Note that if you double click on the pasted content in Word, it will open up an Excel editable object. You can edit the formatting here.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I tried. It is pasting it as an image. I'd like to paste it as a table.

Comment: It's not an image. If you double click on it, it will be an Excel object (table) that you can edit